# Combine Multiple Row into One Row

Tags: mysql, sql

I've some issue when trying to query mysql.
I've some data like below :

[image]

but at the same time, I Want to join all data in just One Date, just like this :

[image]

CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME ???

Here's Below my query :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(PRAY_TIME, '%d-%m-%Y') 'SCH_DATE',
IF(PRAY_SCH = 'Subuh', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_SUB(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 17 HOUR), 8), 5), '-') 'SUBUH',
IF(PRAY_SCH = 'Dzuhur', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_SUB(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 5 HOUR), 8), 5), '-') 'DZUHUR',
IF(PRAY_SCH = 'Ashar', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_ADD(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 8), 5), '-') 'ASHAR',
IF(PRAY_SCH = 'Maghrib', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_ADD(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 8), 5), '-') 'MAGHRIB',
IF(PRAY_SCH = 'Isya', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_ADD(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 8), 5), '-') 'ISYA'
FROM T_TABLE_ADZAN_2018 WHERE ID_CITY = '1'
ORDER BY DATE(PRAY_TIME) ASC;
```

Comment: Are you sure about that, your desired output is correct ??

Comment: This problem stems from poor design. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: Don't post input/output data as images. ***Use text!*** It's _much easier_ to produce test data from ***text***.

Comment: What are your ***rules*** for going from input to output? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: @CraigYoung sorry dude...

Comment: @Strawberry I use Workbench, so Poor Of Me...

Comment: @Susang yes, that's sample of design, and already done for result from my  below

Comment: Your choice of GUI is irrelevant. Your schema is flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry Actually I don't think OP has a spread-sheet style schema. I think OP has created confusion due to complete failure to properly describe the schema and source data. Looking at the question query, it seems to be an attempt to retrieve data from a reasonably well normalised schema and the first image is actually the result of that query - _not the "some data" OP suggests_. Basically OP asked poorly, and Gordon provided a good stab at an answer. Who knows whether OP really understands the intricacies and if it's truly correct.

Comment: Regardless, I doubt this question will get further attention and will probably remain very bad. It may as well be closed as it has zero future value.

Comment: @craigyoung I see. Well, anyway, I agree that the question has room for improvement

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(PRAY_TIME, '%d-%m-%Y') as SCH_DATE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRAY_SCH = 'Subuh', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_SUB(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 17 HOUR), 8), 5) END) as SUBUH,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRAY_SCH = 'Dzuhur', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_SUB(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 5 HOUR), 8), 5) END) as DZUHUR,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRAY_SCH = 'Ashar', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_ADD(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 8), 5) END) as ASHAR,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRAY_SCH = 'Maghrib', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_ADD(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 8), 5) END) as MAGHRIB,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRAY_SCH = 'Isya', LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_ADD(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 8), 5) END) as ISYA
FROM T_TABLE_ADZAN_2018
WHERE ID_CITY = 1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(PRAY_TIME, '%d-%m-%Y') ASC;
```

Notes:

- The `GROUP BY` key should be the key that you `SELECT`.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- The use of `MAX()` should do what you want.
- Presumably, `ID_CITY` is a number, so compare it to a number, not a string.
- `CASE` expressions are `ANSI` standard; `IF()` is MySQL-specific.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
select
    DATE_FORMAT(a.PRAY_TIME, '%d-%m-%Y') 'SCH_DATE',
    LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_SUB(b.PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 17 HOUR), 8), 5) as SUBUH,
    LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_SUB(c.PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 5 HOUR), 8), 5) as DZUHUR,
    LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_ADD(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 8), 5) as MAGHRIB,
    LEFT(RIGHT(DATE_ADD(PRAY_TIME, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 8), 5) as ISYA
    from T_TABLE_ADZAN_2018 as a 
    left join T_TABLE_ADZAN_2018 as b on DATE_FORMAT(a.PRAY_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(a.PRAY_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y') and b.PRAY_SCH='Dzuhur'
    left join T_TABLE_ADZAN_2018 as c on DATE_FORMAT(a.PRAY_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(c.PRAY_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y') and b.PRAY_SCH='Ashar'
    left join T_TABLE_ADZAN_2018 as d on DATE_FORMAT(a.PRAY_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(d.PRAY_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y') and b.PRAY_SCH='Maghrib'
    left join T_TABLE_ADZAN_2018 as e on DATE_FORMAT(a.PRAY_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(e.PRAY_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y') and b.PRAY_SCH='Maghrib' WHERE a.ID_CITY = '1'
```